# Put function's return values into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dic = {}
def myfunc():
    return 4,"MyName"

x,y = myfunc()
dic[x] = y
```

Is there any way to write lines 5 and 6 in one line?

Comment: `tup` is a **dictionary**, not a tuple.

Comment: `tup` is not a tuple, is a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, clarify if what you want is working with dictionaries or tuples and then don't use `dict`, it is the Python name for defining dictionaries. And yes, you can retrieve a value to a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'foo':'value'}
def myfunc():
    return 4,"MyName"

x, mydict[x] = myfunc()
print mydict
```

Returns:

```
{'foo': 'value', 4: 'MyName'}
```

Comment: Thanks, another question if myfunc() some times return Flase as first value like this: (Flase, "") can I combine this assignment with if clause? maybe like this: x,tup[x] = myfunc() if x

Comment: You can't do that, you should use an extra variable for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list of tuples with the dictionary constructor like this:

```
>>> values = (4, "MyName")
>>> d = dict([values])
>>> d
{4: 'MyName'}
```

So you could just do

```
>>> d = dict([myfunc()])
>>> d
{4: 'MyName'}
```

If you have an already existing dictionary that you want to update, you could do it like this:

```
>>> dct = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> dct.update(dict([myfunc()]))
>>> dct
{'foo': 'bar', 4: 'MyName'}
```